# Can I download the Stack Exchange Android app for CyanogenMod without Google apps?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, android-app

I'm one of those exceptions that deviates from the norm: I run CyanogenMod without any Google apps.

Is it possible to download the Stack Exchange Android app .apk directly?

Comment: [How can I download an APK file from the Play Store?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/12330/267)

Comment: I was able to get a copy from [APK Mirror](http://www.apkmirror.com/), which is hosted by [Android Police](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/11/19/meet-apk-mirror/) and seems more trustworthy than some of the alternatives.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Currently our application is heavily reliant on Google's add-ons. We use two-way Google Cloud Messaging, Google Sign-In and more.

At this point we don't think it would make sense for us to test everything on both regular phones and phones without Google's add-ons installed due to the fact that we'd have to double our testing to support a small minority of users. Not to mention the headaches caused by manually giving out APKs since we lose the automatic updating features or even update notifications at all. If this becomes a bigger issue, we'll obviously rethink this.

At the moment our official stance is  that if you can somehow get the APK to your phone and get it to not crash, that's fine go ahead and use it, however we won't be supporting it.

Comment: *"a small minority of users"* - China and Iran don't allow the Google Play store. They represent a significant percentage of the world's population. I hope you might rethink this.

Comment: @Suragch I was born and raised in Iran, I know the stats :) the "user" here is "our collective userbase", and China and Iran combined are a small section of our website's page views. I'm more than happy to reconsider this but we're still _very_ reliant on Google Play Services.