# Web only app for iOS devices <iOS7

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, ios, mobile-app

Now that the mobile theme for Stack Exchange sites [was refreshed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234717/mobile-web-refresher), can we have an app that simply displays this site in a headless webview? (I mean no navbar and hide the tab, bookmarks, and backward buttons at the bottom) and maybe add little safari fullscreen like navigation buttons and a fixed header would be nice too.

I'm asking because the [Stack Exchange app in the appstore](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/05/stack-exchange-for-iphone-is-here/) is not available for iOS < 7, which I can understand. But I think there are some users who cannot update to iOS 7 and this app isn't that much work. Maybe someone from Stack Overflow etc. can build this app, when the Stack Exchange guys don't want to, in fact I would do it, if I had a OSX machine ( ._.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [App Store Approval Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html), under 
2.12:

> Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected

So if the app has only a webview/browser without many native iOS integrations, it will be rejected. Not saying Stack Exchange could put some effort into getting something like push notifications into a browser only app and get it approved somehow.

But, seeing that the mobile team [isn't releasing a copy of the Android app without using the Play Store for unsupported OSes/devices/configurations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217762/can-i-download-the-stack-exchange-android-app-for-cyanogenmod-without-google-app) when the OS natively supports side loading apps, I doubt the team will really want to put the effort into entire app to support older versions of iOS.

As you stated, the community can definitely build their own app. The official apps use the [same public write API that we have access to](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs).